# how to use windows default voice using java?

Tags: java, windows, text-to-speech

In mac we can use something like `RunTime.getRunTime().exe("Say \hello world\")`;
for making our java program speak strings, using the say command, is there any way of doing something similar in windows with java?

Comment: @4castle , It is not... I'm asking how to use it in java,  the user asked "Is there a way to use the MS Speech utility from command line? I can do it on a mac, but can't find any reference to it on Windows XP".... I don't mean to be rude, but I think you didn't even read my question

Comment: Yes, I read your question. You already know how to execute commands from Java, so now the question is just a matter of knowing what command to execute. The dupe question isn't outdated.